# Make div go to next column everry time it's value is divisible by 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

I have this array mapping and it renders out what is expected, but the problem is, I wan't to make that if the number items is divisible by five, it will go on the next column, and the question is, how can I make the div, go to the next column every time that it's value is divisible by 5 while the orientation of divs is still on a vertical alignment?

This is the code I created and it's just rendering the list of item vertically without it going to other side

```
renderLogic() {
    let items = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
    return items.map((item) => {
        if(item % 5 === 0) {
            return (
                <div key = {item} style={{float: 'left'}}>
                    {item}
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div key = {item}>
                    {item}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
 }

render() {
  return  (
    <div className="sample-container">
      {this.renderLogic()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the output of this code was

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11 
12
13
14
```

my expected output was

```
1  6  11
2  7  12
3  8  13
4  9  14
5  10
```

Comment: Next line or next...column? From your expected output it looks like you mean next column.

Comment: you need to use `item % 5 === 0` instead of `items > 5` in your conditional to give the float left style to the appropiate items. Moreover, even if 5 and 10 have the float style, the output will not be what you expect since this isn't how css-floats work

Comment: @AdrianPop okay thanks, I already updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `div`s have `display:block` by default, which makes them occupy the full line. You could solve this problem by setting them to `display:inline-block`.

However, there's a much easier way to deal with your problem. There's no need to use JS (or `float`... yurgh). Just use Flexbox (a CSS rule) and you're done :

```css
.container {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: green dashed 2px;
  height: 120px;
}

span {
  height : 20%;
  background: lightgreen;
  outline: blue solid 1px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
  <span>11</span>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>13</span>
  <span>14</span>
</div>
```

Here's [a complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Yes, but adding a simple property as `margin: 5px` to your code will break everything. You'll have either to use padding + another span element, or you'll have to rethink and recalculate the proportions.

Comment: Indeed, but that's another problem. The 5 elements per column problem is solved. If  you want padding or margin, then this code will be slightly different (because it's another problem).

Comment: Well, it might be another problem, but sometimes it's better to anticipate it and maybe avoid it :)

Comment: Anyway, if you want a gutter between the columns and/or the rows, adding a margin won't work (because you'll always have unwanted margin either on the left or on the right). In that case, you'd have to use Grid, not Flex.

Comment: it's correct, i just use `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: flex` to get the expected output

Answer (score 1):

I did it by thinking the other way around. Instead of generating the div elements top to bottom, I generated them one by one on the same line with the appropriate content, switching to a new row when needed. The code should work for any number of rows you want.

A trick I used was the CSS-property [clear](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) (as `clear: both`). The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float, so it's kind of a "reset". This reset occurs when `j = 0`, aka we generate the first element on that line. The `i + divider * j + 1` gives you the index of the current element (you can do the math with a pen and some paper to see that it works accordingly).

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
    renderLogic() {
      let items = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
      let divider = 5;
      let boxes = [];
      
      for (let i = 0; i < divider; ++i) { 
          for (let j = 0; j < items.length / divider + 1; ++j) {
          
              if (i + divider * j >= items.length)
                  continue;
                  
              if (j == 0) {
                   boxes.push((
                    <div key = {i + divider * j + 1} class="box newline">
                        {i + divider * j + 1}
                    </div>
                ))
              } else {
                 boxes.push((
                    <div key = {i + divider * j + 1} class="box">
                        {i + divider * j + 1}
                    </div>
                ))
              }
             
          }
      }
      
      return boxes;
   }

  render() {
    return  (
      <div class="sample-container">
        {this.renderLogic()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.sample-container {
  background-color: green;
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.newline {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Note: I used the `+ 1` in `{i + divider * j + 1}` for display purposes only. Hope it suits your needs. Cheers!

Comment: ...or just don't use JS at all, three lines with Flexbox do the trick :)